# Email Template - Adding Content Per Message - Dynamic Text

Tags: email-template

**Using Email Templates But Being Able To Customize Them Per Email**

The only way I know to add "custom text" to an Email Template would be to add a field to the Account or Contact, and pull that field's content (if any) into the Template.  **This is not ideal, and if not setup well, the message shows up every time the template is sent, instead of "just one time" (could add time-delayed field-clearing to the custom field, but still not ideal)**

Then I believe products such as **Conga Composer** allow something like this, but **that's a huge package to add this one functionality.**

Does anyone have a better solution?

- Salesman wants to send Client an email using a template
- Salesman wants to add a personal message to the template
- Salesman MAY want to  EDIT the template (if allowed to)

Answer (score 0):

You could use VF page to get custom data to use to customize an email sent from apex. But it sounds like the salesman wants to send email from outlook using template- maybe salesforce for outlook.

You could try to get creative by creating an object for "config" records that the user can select for the template customization.